# Trying to get TypeDescriptor.GetProperties to work

Tags: c#, typedescriptor

beginning C# for real. I'm trying to implement TypeDescriptor.GetProperties. In the code I keep on getting an empty collection. I can't figure out why.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
public class SampleObjectToExportI
{
    public Guid Id;
    public DateTime Date;
    public string StringValue;
    public int NumberValue;
    public bool BooleanValue;
    public SampleObjectToExportI(Guid id, DateTime date, string stringValue, int numberValue, bool booleanValue)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Date = date;
        this.StringValue = stringValue;
        this.NumberValue = numberValue;
        this.BooleanValue = booleanValue;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myList = new List<SampleObjectToExportI>();
        myList.Add(new SampleObjectToExportI(Guid.NewGuid(), DateTime.Now, "String4", 400, true));
        myList.Add(new SampleObjectToExportI(Guid.NewGuid(), DateTime.Now, "String5", 500, false));
        myList.Add(new SampleObjectToExportI(Guid.NewGuid(), DateTime.Now, "String6", 600, true));

        foreach (var sampleObjectToExport in myList)
        {
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(sampleObjectToExport))
            {
                string name = descriptor.Name;
                object value = descriptor.GetValue(sampleObjectToExport);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", name, value);
            }
            //Console.WriteLine(sampleObjectToExport.NumberValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have properties, if you want to then this is the syntax:

```
public Guid Id { set; get; }
public DateTime Date { set; get; }
public string StringValue { set; get; }
public int NumberValue { set; get; }
public bool BooleanValue { set; get; }
```

Refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) for more info.

Another way is to keep your code as is and use `Type.GetFeilds()`:

```
foreach (var fieldInfo in typeof(SampleObjectToExportI).GetFields())
```

Comment: great, thanks user#! It's really about the basics, I know. It's a steep hill.